# Hibernate HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question about my hibernate mapping, I am creating a project with Spring and hibernate, I am facing a issue that I can solve it so far and I couldn't find someone able to help me so far, so I mapped the database and did everything as expected but I am receiving this message:

HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: FROM com.inbox.model.Estado

My hibernate.cfg.xml is like this

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://inboxmysqldb.c4lcntgo83fr.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">inboxuser</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxxx</property>


 <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property> -->
 <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
 <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</property>-->
 <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
 
 <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
 <!-- Mapping files -->
 <!-- <mapping class="com.inbox.model.Box"/> -->
 <mapping class="com.inbox.model.Estado"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My class is mapped like this:

```html
package com.inbox.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;


@Entity(name="com.inbox.model.Estado")
@Table(name = "estado", 
uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id"})})
public class Estado implements IdentifierInterface, Serializable{
 
 
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 3625863483844458267L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 
 @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=11)
 private Integer id;
 
 @Column(name="nome", length=20, nullable=true)
 private String nome;
 
 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getNome() {
  return nome;
 }
 public void setNome(String nome) {
  this.nome = nome;
 } 
 
}
```

HibernateUtil:

```html
public class HibernateUtil {
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();    
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
  if (sessionFactory == null) {
   Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
   configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
     .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
   sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
  }
  return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }   
    
 public static Session getSession() {
  return getSessionFactory().openSession();
 }
}
```

As requested follow the query

```html
 public T findById(int id) {
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  try {
   Query byIdQuery = session.createQuery("FROM " + entityClassName + " as c WHERE c.id = :id");
   byIdQuery.setParameter("id", id);
   return (T) byIdQuery.uniqueResult();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new InboxException(e);
  } finally {
   session.close();
  }
 }
```

I ran out of ideas to try fix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the query code, thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can't use dots in `@Entity`'s `name` attribute, can't find related documentation though, but try changing it to simple "Estado" (without fully qualified name).

Comment: @user3707125 To be portable across persistence providers, that's true.  But Hibernate (afaict) doesn't impose that strict naming requirement.

Comment: @Naros I added the query as requested.

Comment: @user3707125 I have the same class and configs in another project that is not Spring and it's working as should be. So I don't think is that the root cause.